# Как запустить исполнения скрипта после AJAX

Tags: ajax

Всем доброго дня. помогите пожалуйста, на сайте подгрузка контента происходит с помощью AJAX. Но после загрузки не срабатывает анимация.
Это вызов анимации:

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
  $(".box.animated").hover(
  function() {
      $(this).addClass('bounce'); // Добавляем класс bounce
     },
     function() {
      $(this).removeClass('bounce'); // Убираем класс
     }
    )})
  </script>
```

А это сам скрипт подгрузки:

```
 var infinite_scroll = {
        loading: {
            img: " <?php echo get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') ?>/img/25.gif",
        },
        "nextSelector":".fetch a",
        "navSelector":".fetch",
        "itemSelector":".box",
        "contentSelector":"#boxes"
        };
    jQuery( infinite_scroll.contentSelector ).infinitescroll( infinite_scroll );
```

Comment: не надо тут чат разводить. комментарии можно оставлять под вопросом и ответом

Answer (score 1):

Буду пробовать угадать.

Вы добавляете событие `hover` сразу после построения DOM дерева(`$(document).ready()`). В этот момент элемента с `class="box animated"` в DOM дереве еще не существует.
Как следствие событие на него не назначено.

Значит Вам нужно назначить событие на элемент `.box.animated` после того, как он был подгружен в разметку. Сделать это можно через `JavaScript`. Но! Мне кажется более чистым подходом - сделать анимацию через `CSS`:

```
.box.animated:hover {
    /*Тут пишите те стили, которые содержал класс .bounce*/
}
```

**UPD**

Если очень сильно хочется использовать именно средства `JS`, тогда вот это:

```
$(".box.animated").hover(
  function() {
    $(this).addClass('bounce'); // Добавляем класс bounce
   },
   function() {
    $(this).removeClass('bounce'); // Убираем класс
   }
)})
```

Нужно исполнять в колбэке `ajax` запроса, а не в колбэке document ready.

У объекта `$.ajax`(Если не использовать модель промисов), за это отвечало поле `success`.

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    success: function() {/*Тут назначаете свой ховер*/}
    ...
})
```

Надеюсь понятно смог объяснить

**UPD 2**

Я понял, у Вас не джиквериевский аджакс, а бесконечная прокрутка. Попробуйте назначить событие таким образом:

```
$(document).on("mouseenter", ".box.animated", function(e) {
    $(this).addClass('bounce');
}).on("mouseleave", ".box.animated", function(e){
    $(this).removeClass('bounce');
});
```

Comment: Откуда у вас в событии hover взялся тип mouseenter?

Comment: Это не у меня, а у JQuery взялся :)

Comment: Я вообще не вижу у них события hover, только одноименный хелпер.

Comment: Я вижу что начиная с версии 1.9 такой финт ушами не работает. Исправлю чуть ответ